# How to restore working directory after git reset

Tags: node.js, git

I accidentally committed my config file so I ran `git reset --hard HEAD~1` which worked but I now have a new problem. This is a `node.js` project and I have my `node_modules` in my `.gitignore` and have never committed it. After reverting back to the previous commit and reinstalling my modules, my project wont run and I am having trouble figuring out what is wrong with the new modules. Can I restore the working directory I had 2 commands ago somehow? Resetting to a different reference doesn't seem to be the answer on account of my never committing the modules.

Comment: As a followup though, which modules are giving you troubles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git can only restore things that it tracks, so there wouldn't be a way to have it restore your modules to where they were.  I take it your `package.json` doesn't specify the entire version for each module?

If you've deployed this project anywhere, you could get the modules there and see what version they are.  You might even be able to scp them down to your development environment.